# Android multiple activities access one java class

Tags: java, android

I am new to android development and appreciate any help.
I have multiple android activities that have to access one java class. This class has synchronized getters and setters, but I'm having problems making a single instance of this class across the activities. Is there any way to easily do this?

Comment: what about making the class a static class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a ['singleton'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) pattern:

```
public final class Singleton {
    private final static Singleton ourInstance = new Singleton();
    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return ourInstance;
    }

    // Contructor is private, so it won't be possible 
    // to create instance of this class from outside of it.
    private Singleton() {
    }
}
```

Now in your child classes, just use:

```
Singleton.getInstance()
```

to access one, single object of this class.

Comment: so I would cut the code out of the old class file and paste it into this?

Comment: Basically, yeah. Or just make your class' constructor private, then add ourInstance static variable and getInstance() static method. See [wikipedia for a nice example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#Eager_initialization)

Answer (score 0):

you can use [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) design pattern. Here is one way of implementing it in java

```
public class Singleton 
{
  private static Singleton uniqInstance;

  private Singleton() 
  {
  }

  public static synchronized Singleton getInstance() 
  {
    if (uniqInstance == null) {
      uniqInstance = new Singleton();
    }
  return uniqInstance;
  } 
 // other useful methods here
}
```