# How to pass database objects between activities (Android)

Tags: android

Is there any way to pass database object between activities. I have already tried the following ways for doing this.

1. Implementing interface.
2. Using functions.

Comment: Create a singleton that stores your database connection and result objects if you wish.

Answer (score 6):

I guess you are looking for a Singleton. Maybe this will help you:

- [Android multiple activities access one java class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15272457/android-multiple-activities-access-one-java-class)

If you are using a **SQLiteOpenHelper** I HIGHLY recommend you to read this:

- [Correctly Managing Your SQLite Database](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/correctly-managing-your-sqlite-database.html)

I think you should be fine with **Approach #1** which uses a singleton with the abstract factory pattern. Read the article its very informative.
More on the topic and Pros n cons are [here](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/why-you-should-use-loadermanager.html)

Comment: super, best, amazing, brilliant answer! great thanks

Answer (score -1):

There are several approaches that you can follow such as the use of **Intent.putExtra()** to pass your data objects from one activity to another